# Using my own keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

I have a customized keyboard, that is installed, and is used when you change input method.
I would like to use this keyboard in my application, not as an installed soft keyboard, but as a keyboard that pops only in my application\part of the application.

How can I do this (and use same code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an example http://code.google.com/p/android-misc-widgets/source/browse/trunk/android-misc-widgets/src/org/miscwidgets/widget/VirtualKeyboard.java?r=17

Comment: Nice. Can it be modified and used in my application?

Comment: yeah its stand alone, download the whole project, build it, and take a look at how they do it.  adding it to an activity is as simple as this http://code.google.com/p/android-misc-widgets/source/browse/trunk/android-misc-widgets/src/org/miscwidgets/TestVirtualKeyboard.java?r=17